# Пропадание тени при использовании columns

Tags: html, css, css3

Как видно на примере, в некоторых местах у блоков пропадает тень. Как избежать этого? Маргин не помогает, увеличение расстояния между колонками тоже.

```css
.content-wrap {
  max-width: 1000px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: #fafafa;
  padding: 0 20px;
  -webkit-columns: 230px;
  -moz-columns: 230px;
  columns: 230px;
  -webkit-column-gap: 20px;
  -moz-column-gap: 20px;
  column-gap: 20px;
}
article {
  height: 200px;
  width: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px;
  background: #f9f9f9;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
  margin: 5px;
}
article header {
  height: 30%;
  background: #a85;
}
article .content {
  height: 70%;
  background: #666;
}
```

```html
<div class="content-wrap">
  <article>
    <header></header>
    <div class="content"></div>
  </article>
  <article>
    <header></header>
    <div class="content"></div>
  </article>
  <article>
    <header></header>
    <div class="content"></div>
  </article>
  <article>
    <header></header>
    <div class="content"></div>
  </article>
  <article>
    <header></header>
    <div class="content"></div>
  </article>
  <article>
    <header></header>
    <div class="content"></div>
  </article><article>
    <header></header>
    <div class="content"></div>
  </article>
  <article>
    <header></header>
    <div class="content"></div>
  </article>
  <article>
    <header></header>
    <div class="content"></div>
  </article>
  <article>
    <header></header>
    <div class="content"></div>
  </article>
</div>
```

Comment: нигде она не пропадает, все норм, просто у вас смещение вниз, поэтому внизу тень больше чем вверху.

Comment: @Jean-Claude какой у вас браузер? я в хроме отчетливо вижу, в некоторых местах тени нет, что на этом примере, что вживую на рабочем сайте

Comment: проблемное место article width 100%

Comment: добавьте * {
    box-sizing: border-box;
} и тогда границы/отступы войдут в эту ширину  article 100%

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблемное место `article { width: 100%}`
Добавьте * { box-sizing: border-box; } и тогда границы/отступы войдут в эту ширину article 100%.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.content-wrap {
  max-width: 1000px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: #fafafa;
  padding: 0 20px;
  -webkit-columns: 230px;
  -moz-columns: 230px;
  columns: 230px;
  -webkit-column-gap: 20px;
  -moz-column-gap: 20px;
  column-gap: 20px;
}
article {
  height: 200px;
  width: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px;
  background: #f9f9f9;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  margin: 5px;
}
article header {
  height: 30%;
  background: #a85;
}
article .content {
  height: 70%;
  background: #666;
}
```

```html
<div class="content-wrap">
  <article>
    <header></header>
    <div class="content"></div>
  </article>
  <article>
    <header></header>
    <div class="content"></div>
  </article>
  <article>
    <header></header>
    <div class="content"></div>
  </article>
  <article>
    <header></header>
    <div class="content"></div>
  </article>
  <article>
    <header></header>
    <div class="content"></div>
  </article>
  <article>
    <header></header>
    <div class="content"></div>
  </article>
  <article>
    <header></header>
    <div class="content"></div>
  </article>
  <article>
    <header></header>
    <div class="content"></div>
  </article>
  <article>
    <header></header>
    <div class="content"></div>
  </article>
  <article>
    <header></header>
    <div class="content"></div>
  </article>
</div>
```